# Find arg(min) when global min is known

Tags: nonconvex-programming

Suppose we are trying to optimize a uniformly continuous function with multiple critical points.

If the value of global minimum is already known before optimization, can we find arg(min) within polynomial time?

Numerical methods (i.e. gradient descents) typically only consider about first derivative, thus feel difficult to tell differences between local/ global min). However, I think at least in this special problem, “knowing value of global min” is helpful for finding arg(min).

Comment: How did you get the global minimum in the first place? Can any portion of that procedure be reused to inform the secondary search?

Comment: When you say `arg(min)`, do you mean `argmin` in the Numpy sense (i.e. the index of the minimum), or something else like the complex argument?

Comment: @Reinderien Thank you for your response!    

1. Sometimes value of global min is known. Suppose you have a curve (but parameters unknown) and some points generated from the curve. Suppose this curve is well-determined by these points. When using OLS to estimate the parameters, we will find minimum value of SSE is zero.  
2. arg(min) means the inputs of global minimum. Back to the example above, the true parameters of the curve can exactly make SSE=0. Thus, global minimum refers to the lowest possible SSE= 0; while arg(min) refers to inputs (true parameters)

Comment: Do you have an analytic definition of the function and its critical points?

Comment: @Reinderien Yes. The example pre-mentioned is the problem I am trying to solve. 

The objective function is SSE (sum of squared errors). By minimizing SSE to 0, we can find the parameters where data points are generated from.

Comment: If there are any other methods, other than minimizing SSE, can find parameters, these methods would be of help as well @Reinderien

Comment: Extrapolating somewhat, this is the kind of thing that scipy's `curve_fit` algorithm is specifically designed to do

Comment: @Reinderien extrapolation may not be a good choice. Once using function approximations, it may not be able to find the parameters we are looking for.

Comment: I meant extrapolation metaphorically, as in "your question is very vague and I have to do a lot of inference".

Comment: If you know the function analytically, perhaps a root finding algorithm would work: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: If f* is your known global minima then you can solve: f(x) - f* = 0.